# SharedPreferences Flutter.. Set Expiration Time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sharedpreference

I am making a application in **Flutter**.

I have a access token coming from an API which I save in shared preferences for session management and authentication.

But here the catch is that this token expires every 1 hour so I need to clear the shared preferences every 1 hour ..

Package used - [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

So, How do I do that??

Comment: Are you using a JWT token?

Comment: You can store the token-generated time into share preference then when you need to call API, compare the stored updated token time with Time. now(). If it is 1 hour ago from the current time then remove the token from the share preference regenerate a new token and save the token into the share preference as well as the updated time.

Comment: Why do you need to remove it? If the token is expired the user won't be able to do anything with it anyway. You should just handle the cases when api requests fail because of the token being expired

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I've used one feature-rich package, which helps us to decode the JWT Token. Decoding means extracting the information.

I've used: [jwt_decoder](https://pub.dev/packages/jwt_decoder)

```
import "dart:developer";

import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:jwt_decoder/jwt_decoder.dart";
import "package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const HomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (Duration timeStamp) async {
        await SharedPrefSingleton.instance.initSharedPreferences();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: fun,
            child: const Text("Check JWT Token"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> fun() async {
    // Not Expired Token
    // const String token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyLCJleHAiOjk5OTk5OTk5OTl9.Vg30C57s3l90JNap_VgMhKZjfc-p7SoBXaSAy8c28HA";

    // Expired Token
    const String token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyLCJleHAiOjEyMzQ1Njc4OTB9.Ev7tjNe1-zHZvSeoeEplJ1_xxfWLawVbp_EJXAsdzJU";

    final bool expired = JwtDecoder.isExpired(token);
    log("is token expired: $expired");

    await SharedPrefSingleton.instance.setToken(value: expired ? "New" : token);

    final String getCurrentToken = SharedPrefSingleton.instance.getToken();
    log("CurrentToken: $getCurrentToken");

    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}

class SharedPrefSingleton {
  SharedPrefSingleton._();
  static final SharedPrefSingleton instance = SharedPrefSingleton._();

  SharedPreferences? preferences;

  Future<void> initSharedPreferences() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    log("Loaded and parsed the SharedPreferences for this app from disk.");
    return Future<void>.value();
  }

  Future<bool> setToken({required String value}) async {
    final bool isSaved = await preferences?.setString("jwtKey", value) ?? false;
    log("Token Saved: ${isSaved ? "Successfully" : "Unsuccessfully"}");
    return Future<bool>.value(isSaved);
  }

  String getToken() {
    final String value = preferences?.getString("jwtKey") ?? "";
    log("Token value: $value");
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can handle this scenario better with other approaches, however, if you want to invalidate your token locally based on a validation time you can do this:

```dart
void saveAccessToken(String token) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final now = DateTime.now();

  await prefs.setString('access_token', token);
  await prefs.setString('token_timestamp', now.toIso8601String());
}

Future<String?> getAccessToken() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final token = prefs.getString('access_token');
  final tokenTimestamp = prefs.getString('token_timestamp');

  if (token != null && tokenTimestamp != null) {
    final timestamp = DateTime.parse(tokenTimestamp);
    final currentTime = DateTime.now();
    final tokenDuration = currentTime.difference(timestamp);

    const Duration tokenExpirationDuration = Duration(hours: 1);

    if (tokenDuration <= tokenExpirationDuration) {
      return token;
    } else {
      await clearAccessToken();

      return null;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(hour: 1), (Timer timer) {
  //Clear Shared preference here
});
```

You can clear using this. But it has some limitation regarding background case.